# How to delete a heap allocated std:::array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, pointers, memory-leaks

I have this pointer in a class:

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<Item*, XSize>, YSize>, ZSize>* Items;
```

In the constructor:

```
Items = new std::array<std::array<std::array<Item*, XSize>, YSize>, ZSize>();
```

In the class descructor i have tried calling

```
delete Items;
delete[] Items;
```

but there is a memory leak in my program when i constantly create and delete this type of class

Comment: you need to `delete` what you `new`ed and `delete []` what you `new []`ed. If there is a memory leak with `delete Items;` there is an issue in code you did not post. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: who owns the `Item`s in the array? Who allocates memory for them and who deletes them?

Comment: `delete Items;` is correct. It will delete the `std::array`. However, `delete` never traverses through raw pointers, so none of the `Item` objects will be delete. (In case you are expecting that to happen.). If you want to have the array elements heap-allocated, why do you not simply use `std::vector` instead, which does this for you? Also, if you do heap-allocate, don't use raw `new`. It will only cause you memory leak and double free issues. Use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` instead.

Comment: The rule of thumb is - for each usage of `new`, there is exactly one usage of the corresponding `delete`.   The assignment `Items = new std::array<std::array<std::array<Item*, XSize>, YSize>, ZSize>()` involves exactly one usage of `new`, to create a `std::array<std::array<std::array<Item*, XSize>, YSize>, ZSize>` which (because of the `()` at the end) is default initialised.   The corresponding usage of `delete` is `delete Items`.  This does not affect any of the `Item *`s stored in your 3D array of pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided did not detect a memory leak.  In additionif `delete[]` is used,  an obvious warning will occur:

> Warning C6279 'Items' is allocated with scalar new, but deleted with array delete[]